# Tweetstream printing tweets to console but not page

Tags: twitter-streaming-api, tweetstream

I'm using the tweetstream gem and the tweets I'm tracking show up on the console but not on the page when I load it. Here's the action in my controller:

```
def stream
TweetStream::Client.new.track('javascript') do |status|
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

end

And here's the view:

```
<% TweetStream::Client.new.track('javascript') do |status| %>
  <%= puts "[#{status.user.screen_name}] #[{status.text}]" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my first Rails app so I'm pretty new at this. Anyone know why it's printing to the console but not showing up in the view?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have to pull the Tweetstream from a database.  So set up a Daemon using:

```
TweetStream::Daemon.new('tracker', :log_output => true).track("twitter junk") do |tweet|
      ######put tweet.text into db############
end
```

Start daemon from console  with:

```
ruby daemonname.rb start
```

from application pull tweets from db.